# How can I convert sequences to sharings and vice versa?

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, integer-sequence

Given positive integers $k,n$, a $k$-sequence of $I_n$ is a list of $k$ not necessarily distinct elements of $\{1,\dots, n\}$. And an $n$-sharing of $I_k$ is a list of $n$ possibly empty, disjoint subsets of $\{1,\dots, k\}$ that union up to $\{1,\dots, k\}$. There is a one-to-one correspondence between the $k$-sequences of $I_n$ and the $n$-sharings of $I_k$, where the $i$th element of the sharing contains all indices $j$ of the sequence that store the number $i$. For example, the $3$-sequence
$$(4, 1, 1)$$
of $I_4$ is mapped to the $4$-sharing
$$(\{2,3\}, \varnothing, \varnothing, \{1\})$$
of $I_3$ because the two indices storing a $1$ in the sequence are $2$ and $3$, the only index in the sequence storing a $4$ is $1$, and there are no indices storing $2$ or $3$. How can I convert between $k-$sequences of $I_n$ and $n$-sharings of $I_k$ in mathematica?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a case for [`PositionIndex`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html):

```
ClearAll[toPositions]
toPositions = PositionIndex[#] /@ Range[Max@#] /. _Missing -> {} &;
```

**Examples:**

```
toPositions @ {4, 1, 1}
```

> ```
> {{2, 3}, {}, {}, {1}}
> ```

```
toPositions @ {5, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 5, 5}
```

> ```
> {{}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {}, {1, 5, 7, 8}}
> ```

To recover the input list from positions:

```
ClearAll[fromPositions]
fromPositions = Values @* KeySort @* 
  KeyValueMap[Sequence @@ Thread[List /@ # -> First@#2] &]
    @* KeyDrop[{{}}] @* PositionIndex;
```

***Examples:***

```
fromPositions@{{2, 3}, {}, {}, {1}}
```

> ```
>  {4, 1, 1}
> ```

```
fromPositions@{{}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {}, {1, 5, 7, 8}}
```

> ```
>  {5, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 5, 5}
> ```

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = RandomChoice[Range@6, 10]
```

> ```
> {5, 3, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1}
> ```

```
toPositions@list
```

> ```
> {{4, 6, 7, 9, 10}, {5}, {2, 8}, {}, {1, 3}}
> ```

```
fromPositions @ %
```

> ```
> {5, 3, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1}
> ```

```
SeedRandom[1]
lists = RandomChoice[Range@7, {100, 20}];

AllTrue[fromPositions@toPositions@# == # &] @ lists
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! Just one question: what's the underscore in front of `Missing` in the `toPositions` function? Is it like the wildcard in Ocaml?

Comment: @user236343, see [Blank (_)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) in the documentation center.

Answer (score 2):

```
ToPositions[kseq_List] := Module[{sharing, idxseq},
sharing = Array[{} &, Max@kseq];
idxseq = {ConstantArray[#, Length@#], Range@Length@#} &@kseq;
MapThread[AppendTo[sharing[[#1[[#2]]]], #2] &, idxseq];
sharing]

FromPositions[sharing_List] := Module[{ord, srange, seq},
ord = Ordering[Catenate[sharing]];
srange = Range@Length@sharing;
seq = Splice@ConstantArray[#, Length[sharing[[#]]]] & /@ srange;
seq[[ord]]]
```

**test1**

```
l1 = {4, 1, 1};

ToPositions@l1
```

> {{2, 3}, {}, {}, {1}}

```
FromPositions@ToPositions@l1 === l1

(*True*)
```

**test2**

```
l2 = {5, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 5, 5};

ToPositions@l2
```

> {{}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {}, {1, 5, 7, 8}}

```
FromPositions@ToPositions@l2 === l2

(*True*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ToPositions[x_] :=
 Lookup[PositionIndex @ x, Range @ Max @ x, {}]

FromPositions[x_] :=
 Map[First] @ SortBy[Last] @ Apply[Join] @ Map[Thread] @
     Transpose[{Range @ Length @ x, x}]
```

**test 1**

```
al = {4, 1, 1};

ToPositions @ al
```

{{2, 3}, {}, {}, {1}}

```
FromPositions @ ToPositions @ al
```

{4, 1, 1}

**test 2**

```
bl = {5, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 5, 5};

ToPositions @ bl
```

{{}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {}, {1, 5, 7, 8}}

```
FromPositions @ ToPositions @ bl
```

{5, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 5, 5}